# Conditional Probability: Mentioning Probability X-Times in terms of probability

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I am practicing for my Probability exam, and here's a question that I am unable to solve.

The question is from **Introduction to Probability by Joseph K. Blitzstein
Jessica Hwang**

Question says that it is 23 times more likely for a smoker to develop lung cancer than a non-smoker, and 21.6% men in U.S smoke. We are required to find probability that a person is a smoker, if he develops cancer.

I believe the question is related to Conditional probability but I am not sure how to right **23 times more likely** in terms of **probability**. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

So far I have defined two events:

A: Man has cancer.

B: Man Smokes.

We have P(B), and I believe we need to find P(B|A), I am stuck and don't know how to move forward.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: Thank you! :) Hoping to get a response soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(A)$ be the probability that a man has cancer. You can partition this probability over other events. There are 2 such partitions - a man smokes and a man does not smoke.

$$P(A | \text{ man smokes }) = 23P(A| \text{ man does not smoke})$$

Also notice that $P(A) = P(A | \text{ man smokes }).P( \text{ man smokes }) + P(A| \text{ man does not smoke}).P( \text{ man does not smoke })$

You are given that $P(\text{ man smokes }) = 0.216$. Can you now apply Bayes theorem?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer, hope it helps : )

[image: calculation of probabilities]